# How is it possible to pass the getFilesDir() to Files object :as getFilesDir() returns path of the dir?

Tags: android

I am new to Java ,so please someone explain to me this stuff:

```
res = getResources();     
try {
        IO.transferFiles(getFilesDir(),res);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

the above code is in `OnCreate()`.

```
class IO{
public static void transferFiles(File base, Resources res) throws IOException {
    //statement
        }

}}
```

So my question is, what will happen if we pass `getFilesDir()` method to File Object (here `base`).
(please provide any links if you can from where I could learn more)

Comment: 'plz' = 'please', 'u' = 'you' and please read the tour and help pages about what expect in a question.  We are not a tutorial site

Comment: please tell what you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: [example](http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.content.Context/getFilesDir)
It returns the absolute file path of the internal storage of the device for which no permission is required. But when u want to read a file using that or write a file then  you need to declare   `<uses-permission>` in Manifest file.
For [example](http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.content.Context/getFilesDir)

[Internal and external file storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)